# Python CSV Row removal dependent on row number

Tags: python, csv, indexing, delete-row

I have a python system where it loads questions and answers from separate csv files for a quiz based program using tkinter. I can load the files, display them, allow the user to add more questions and more.

I'm stuck on finding a way to use python to delete a row dependent on questionNo (my row counter). The system works by them navigating to the question using next and previous buttons and then pressing delete on a question they don't like. So I have access to the questionNo (the index of the row that I want to delete) but don't know how to delete it using python.

Any help will be appreciated. I'd have included my code but a lot of it is contextual to my program (A level coursework) and this is just a small section of it. **I DO NOT WANT TO USE ANOTHER CSV FILE AS A TEMPORARY.**

Comment: If you don't want to use another temp file you are going to have to store all the rows, remove whatever you want from the list and then overwrite the original file

Answer (score 0):

If you use pandas' package, you can drag your csv files into your RAM and then use it as you want, before saving it and erasing your previous file. It's very powerful for working on csv, and does not use any temp csv.
To open your files and load them in a Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
questions = pd.read_csv('questions.csv')
answers = pd.read_csv('answers.csv')
```

You can add an index to these Dataframes by:

```
questions = pd.read_csv('questions.csv', columns = my_columns, index = my_index)
```

Then to erase a line:

```
questions = questions.drop(number_of_your_question)
answers = answers.drop(number_of_your_answer)
```

And to save the files:

```
questions.to_csv
answers.to_csv
```

Comment: Can't seem to get pip to work to install it, keeps giving me errors. I will update you soon if I can get it to work because this was the sort of solution I was searching for.

Comment: Got it working but I don't understand how to assign an index and what the index should be so that I can use a variable to remove a line later.

Comment: You will use the horizontal index. It's what you set with the "index = my_index" option.
By default the index of your dataframe looks like a list basicly containing the numbers of the row.
then by typing questions = questions.drop(number_of_your_question, you recreate the dataframe by "forgetting" the row [i] where i is the number of your question.
Note that the index won't be changed, so that if you erase the 4th question, the new 4th question will still have 5 for index as it was the 5th question to begin with. To avoid that you have to type: df.reset_index().drop('index',1)